# How Do I Preserve My AWS Amplify Login When Running Cypress Tests?

Tags: typescript, cypress, aws-amplify

Currently, I have a `beforeEach()` that logs cypress in before the test starts. However, this is rather slow. How do I sustain that logged in user, between tests?

My goal is to navigate through all the pages of the logged in user, and to check for console warnings and errors.

**Code:**

```
describe('Candidate Pages', () => {
  beforeEach(() => cy.loginByCognito(Cypress.env("candidate_username"), Cypress.env("candidate_password")));
  candidateRoutes.forEach((page) => {
    it(`No Console Errors for ${page}`, () => checkConsole(page, "error"));
    it(`No console.warn for ${page}`, () => checkConsole(page, "warn"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look on the same [page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/amazon-cognito-authentication#Login-with-cyorigin) where you found `cy.loginByCognito()`, you see the session example

> Lastly, we can refactor our login command to take advantage of cy.session() to store our logged in user ***so we don't have to reauthenticate with everything test***.

If you didn't read that far, I suggest you add it in.

```js
// cypress/support/auth-provider-commands/cognito.ts
// Amazon Cognito
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByCognito', (username, password) => {
  cy.session(
    `cognito-${username}`,
    () => {
      return loginToCognito(username, password)
    },
    {
      validate() {
        cy.visit('/')
        // revalidate our session to make sure we are logged in
        cy.contains('Get Started').should('be.visible')
      },
    }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as any login that sets a token, use `cy.session()`

> Once created, a session for a given id is cached for the duration of the spec file.

```js
const login = (name) => {
  cy.session(name, () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
    cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
    cy.get('#submit').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/home')
  })
  cy.visit('/home')
}

beforeEach(() => {
  login('user')
})
```

Also

> To persist a session across multiple specs, use the option cacheAcrossSpecs=true.

In this case, move the code to /support/e2e.js.